# Vector space of a sequence of scalars

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Struggling slightly with the following question, not sure how to proceed:

Let $c_{0}$ be the vector space of sequences of scalars $(a_{n})_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$ such that $a_{n} \to 0 $ as $ n \to \infty $. Prove that $c_0$ is a closed set in $(\ell_0, ||\cdot||_{\infty})$.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: You need to prove that for  any convergent sequence in $c_0$, the limit is still in $c_0$

Comment: By $\ell_0$ do you mean the set of bounded sequences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closed sets in metric spaces are characterised by the fact that they contain all limits of convergent sequences. Convergence in $l^\infty$ (and therefore in $c_0$ or any other subspace) is uniform convergence.

So you need to show that a uniformly convergent sequence of $c_0$ sequences is still $c_0.$ Can you do that using the $\epsilon$ definition of uniform convergence?